# How to change the class of an element by clicking on another element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How i can change the `class` of an HTML element (X:element) when i click on `<a>`, and when i click on other elements (div,body,li), the class of this element  (X:element)  change
This is the example:

```
<a class='A'></a>
<div class='click'></div>
```

When i click on `a` `addClass` ( B )

When i click on other elements `removeClass`:( B )

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please edit your question and be as clear as possible, thank you.

Comment: You want to change `id` or `class`? If `class` please correct your question title..

Comment: in javascript, an elements class is accessed using either the `classname` property, or its `classList` object with add/remove methods - or in jqueery, it's a no brainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var aTag = $("a.A");
  var divTarget = $("div.click");
  
   $(document).click(function(e){
     var target = $(e.target);
     if(target.is(aTag)){
        if(divTarget.hasClass("B"))
          divTarget.removeClass("B");
        else
          divTarget.addClass("B");
     }
     else if(!target.is(divTarget))
     {
       $(divTarget).removeClass("B");
     }
  });
  
})
```

```css
.B{
  color: blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class='A'>Link A</a>
<div class='click'>Click Div</div>
<div class='click1'>Click Div 1</div>
<div class='click2'>Click Div 2</div>
```

Comment: not the div is clicked 
when you click on other element (any element except the A and div.click)

Comment: Click on 'Link A' change the color of 'Click Div'

Comment: you mean to say add class `B` to any element which is getting clicked and remove it from previous one?

Comment: when i click on <a> we addClass in the <div>
when i click in other element we remove the class from the div 
or when i click again on <a>  we remove the class from the div 
that's all
if you don't understand i can show you a demo

Comment: what should happen if 'Click Div' already has a added class due to previous click on <a>; and now I click on this <div> itself? does the added class should get removed?

Comment: no
 if you click on the <div> it self 
the added class should not get removed

Comment: please see if that's what you are looking for...!

Comment: this is the solution tnnxx you

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you right, you talk about something like this:

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
       $('.A').removeClass('B');
    });
$('.A').on('click',function(e){
       $('.A').addClass('B');
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question, I add class B to .click if you click on A, clicking anywhere else, I remove it

```js
    $(function() {
      $(document).on("click", function(event) {
        var $tgt = $(event.target);
        $(".click").toggleClass("B", $tgt.hasClass('A'))
      });
    });
```

```css
.B { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='A'>Click here</a>
<div class='click'>Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should work...

```
$('.a').on('click', function(){

    $(this).addClass('B');
});

$('.click').on('click', function(){

    $('.a').removeClass('B');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the 'a' tag will add the class **B** to the 'div' with the class **click**.

When anything but the 'div' with the class **click** is clicked the class **B** is removed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".A").on("click", function() {
        $(".click").addClass("B");
        return false;  // prevents the page from being reloaded
    });
    $(document).on("click", function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('click')) {
            $(".click").removeClass("B");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: When any other element (not the div.click) is clicked the class B is removed.